# Trouble with Python CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
reader = csv.reader("a,b,c", delimiter=",")
for r in reader:
    print r
```

outputs:

```
['a']
['', '']
['b']
['', '']
['c']
```

I've tried with and without delimiter.  Ideally I'd like my deliminator to be; but I can't even get this simple example to work...

Comment: You're supposed to pass a file or file-like object to `csv.reader`, not `"a,b,c"`.

Comment: what do you mean this example doesnt work?  `csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `csv.reader()` is not at all typical. Typically, one passes a `file`-like object, not a string. The typical use is like so:

```
with open('some_file.csv', 'rb') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    for r in reader:
        # do something with "r"
        pass
```

Technically, the passed-in parameter doesn't have to be a `file`. All it has to be is an iterable sequence of strings. So, your (fairly odd) example might give the results you expect if you pass in a list, not a single string:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(["a,b,c"], delimiter=",")
for r in reader:
    print r
```

Result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

The csv reader needs a file like object, so write the string `"a,b,c"` into a file like described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) (chapter 13.1.1):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Or use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html).